# How to use DPI scaling factor (float) to set margins (int)

Tags: android, compatibility, resolution, fragmentation

My Android app looks great at 480x800 pixels resolution but it breaks at LDPI screen with 240x400 pixels. I know I can get scaling factor of screen in activity using `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density` which would give the exact `float` value depending upon screen resolution.

In my app, I have used `RelativeLayout` and `ImageView`s within it, and set the margins of images using `setMargins()`, as this method uses pixels in `int` for its top, left, bottom and right values, **how can I set these values using DPI factor I got?** (which is a float). We have `Math.floor()` but I'm positioning images at very particular locations using pixels, and DPI factor returned by method has very specific value at decimal places which can't be ignored, so casting to `int` doesn't work for me.

**Update**

Also, I use `lp.setMargins(100,200,0,0);` to set the margins, what modification I'll be making in it to use DPI factor I recieved from device?

P.S. I know its more a mathematical issue rather than programming, but I'm poor with math, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like I was too early to ask the question instead of fiddling myself, but also noticed that I'm not AT ALL the first to face this issue.

So, here's solution I found.

I created a following method in my Activity class.

```
private int px(float dips)
{
    float DP = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return Math.round(dips * DP);
}
```

This would convert given `dp` value into appropriate pixels. You can make the variable `DP` used in method to be global and initialize it in your `onCreate()` method rather than within `px()`, just to make method execute fast.

Usage:

```
lp.setMargins(px(100),px(200), 0, 0);
```

OR, if you don't create `px()` just for this and have `DP` as global.

```
lp.setMargins(100 * Math.round(DP), 200 * Math.round(DP), 0, 0);
```

However, using method makes it look much cleaner and readable. :-)