# Setting margin to ImageView using float values

Tags: android, floating-point, margin, parameters

I have an ImageView for which I want to pass float values as Top and Left margin. I have these 2 values to set as Top and Left margin.

```
float valTop = 3.5;
float valueLeft = 6.8;
```

I have this code. But I have to roundup the margin values to int value.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
        params.leftMargin = Math.round(valLeft);
        params.topMargin = Math.round(valTop);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Is there any way to directly set float value as margin ?

Comment: why `float` value? do you have any problem with `int`?

Comment: You have to convert this into pixel and then set ... Try..

[this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177009/how-to-use-dpi-scaling-factor-float-to-set-margins-int

Comment: Its a graph. And I need to set the point in x and y axis. And I cannot set 3 for 3.5.

Comment: if you really need float (????) use `View#TRANSLATION_X` / `View#TRANSLATION_Y` property

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: read the View#TRANSLATION_X/Y javadocs